# pdf2swf works only on ssh

Tags: php, permissions, exec, pdf2swf

i have the following execute command:

```
/usr/local/bin/pdf2swf -s centerx=1 -s bitmap -s jpegquality=85 -s zoomtowidth=1200 -s zoomtoheight=1000 -s zoom=100 -s framerate=0.25 -s subpixels=1.5 -S /test.pdf -o /test-%.swf
```

when i run it via ssh(putty for example) it works perfectly.
but when i run it via php script like following:

```
<?php
exec("/usr/local/bin/pdf2swf -s centerx=1 -s bitmap -s jpegquality=85 -s zoomtowidth=1200 -s zoomtoheight=1000 -s zoom=100 -s framerate=0.25 -s subpixels=1.5 -S /test.pdf -o /test-%.swf");
?>
```

it doesnt work...
please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: try `echo exec("......")`, thus you will know the output of the command execution. You will know that the problem is from the output.

Comment: That will print just the last line. Use this: exec("/usr/local/bin/pdf2swf...", $output); var_dump($output); And you will see what causes the problem.

Comment: it could be a permission problem? maybe the pdf2swf is allowed to run only under root user, and not under apache user?

Comment: Most hosting companies disable commandline access. See if yours does too and if so, ask them to allow you to invoke pdf2swf

Answer (score 0):

You could try [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  Example:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```